# compileSdkVersion matches sdk version but "unsupported version of Gradle"

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk

With the following specs in thee app/build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.iiscenter.shub"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 25
    versionName "2.6.7"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

And the sdk 25 (Android 7) installed

[image]

I get the following error by running "Build APK"

```
The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to menu of your Android Studio and access `File`->`Project Structure` then go to `Project` label and change data to:

```
Gradle version: 4.4
Android Plugin Version: 3.1.2
Android Plugin Repository: google(), jcenter
Default Library Repository: google(), jcenter
```

Press `Ok` and then clean and rebuild project, maybe invalidate caches and restarting before.

Comment: What does this mean `WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.2.
`? Is it important?

Comment: I think this means you have two SDK build tools version and your IDE is ignoring the older. Plus one on my answer for that :D Two questions in one post.