# android build gradle error (android 3.1.3)

Tags: android, gradle, build, configure

I reinstalled my android studio and thereafter i am getting error while building gradle.
I did every change that can help in building gradle but then also it showed error as **"configure build" error**.
so kindly help me so that i can start my android programming.

gradle version - 4.4
android plugin version - 3.1.3`

i have changed google() to maven() but nothing happened.

```
//build.gradle file
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {


repositories {
    google()
  jcenter { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
   jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

Comment: Please see if this is of some help. If so please upvote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50514534/5885018

Comment: This may be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50549261/5885018 - please plus 1

Comment: can you update your question with complete error log?

Comment: ERROR IS:Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1/gradle-3.1.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project